# All the services are not running in Hortonwork sandbox 2.6.5

Tags: hortonworks-sandbox

I am facing a problem with Hortonworks Sanbox 2.6.5 on virtualbox with Ram Size = 10GB and virtualization enabled, but all my services are not running. what is the reason Could you guys help me out.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oFr9b.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Though I would expect this to happen automatically, it may be needed to manually click 'start all services'.

That being said, also please be aware that HDP 2 will be deprecated this year and that you may want to check out the successor [CDP](https://www.cloudera.com/downloads/cdp-data-center-trial.html) instead. The Cloudera Data Platform is recommended for all new cluster setups.

---

Full disclosure: I am an employee of Cloudera, the company behind both CDP and HDP.